# how to show panels of other classes in cardlayout?

Tags: java, swing, oop, cardlayout

i have created this simple program . my problem is that i want to display panels of other classes without opening new JFrame . but i could not create any solution. can some one make simple code to show how to access Panels of other classes and replace current panel ?

```
package cardlayout;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Clayou {

    private JFrame jf = new JFrame("card layout");
    private JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    private JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    private JButton jb1 = new JButton("second");
    private JButton jb2 = new JButton("first");
    private CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    Clayou() {

        jp.setLayout(cl);
        jp1.add(jb1);
        jp2.add(jb2);

        jp1.setBackground(Color.black);
        jp2.setBackground(Color.white);

        jp.add(jp1, "1");
        jp.add(jp2, "2");

        cl.show(jp, "1");

        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(jp, "2");

            }
        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(jp, "1");

            }
        });
        jf.add(jp);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Clayou();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? What about an interface with a method to retrieve the panel? `public interface HasPanel { Component getPanel(); }`

Comment: well i am still not expert at OOP 
so i didn't got what you said 

this program have two panels in this  class and when respective button is  pressed one panel replaces other 

i want to create a panel(s) in other class and replace these panels with that panel(s)  but without creating a new JFrame . i hope you got my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a question which might as well have the same answer as this. [Changing panels in gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243520/changing-panels-in-gui/34244499#34244499) I think this will also help you too. There is class Card which you extend to allow for more card types. I have made two card types for this example.

imports

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
```

main class

```
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {

    Vector<String> menuList = new Vector<>();
    JList<String> menu = new JList<>(menuList);

    JPanel content = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

    Gui(){
        //put menu on left, content in middle
        add(menu, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        menu.addListSelectionListener(this);

        //add multiple cards
        addCard(new SimpleLabelCard("First Item", "First Item Text"));
        addCard(new SimpleLabelCard("Second Item", "Second Item Text"));
        addCard(new SimpleTextAreaCard("Third Item", "Third Item Text"));


        //set content to first item
        ((CardLayout) content.getLayout()).show(content, "First Item");
    }

    private void addCard(Card c){
        menuList.add(c.name);
        content.add(c, c.name);
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.setSize(600, 500);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;

        //set card layout from JList menu
        ((CardLayout) content.getLayout()).show(content, menu.getSelectedValue());
    }
}
```

other classes, put each one in their respective file.

```
//Card.java
//this is the basic card class the extends JPanel
//it contains the name so you can easily switch to it
public class Card extends JPanel{
    public final String name;

    public Card(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

//SimpleLabelCard.java
//extends Card, so it is also a JPanel
public class SimpleLabelCard extends Card{

    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public SimpleLabelCard(String name, String text) {
        super(name);
        label.setText(text);
        add(label);
    }
}

//SimpleTextAreaCard.java
public class SimpleTextAreaCard extends Card{

    private JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

    public SimpleTextAreaCard(String name, String text) {
        super(name);
        this.text.setText(text);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(this.text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

now if you want to make another type of card just extend the card class. I hope this is straight forward enough. It was actually a learning experience for me.

Comment: can you simplify it down to my understanding :) 
just see my code 
i will be really thankfull

Comment: Try running it first and if you need extra help i'll help you. make sure it is what you want.

Comment: Your program have two panels one is fixed i.e button on left second changes with pressing buttons .....
i want to replace them completly with new panel and that new panel should be in different class .

Comment: thanks a lot for help ,
i had to use this method 
 [    card.next(your panel);  ]